# manage_pages permission for an app which uses Graph API but needs no users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have had an app working for literally years. It ran about 150 pages which I set up and had the manage_pages permission to write to it. It had no users apart from me. Indeed keeping it in "development mode" would work fine. But it isn't allowed to work that way it seems

I could generate the page tokens successfully and then use some PHP to update many of the pages at the same time.

Manage_pages seems to have stopped working.

Now the API reports:

OAuthException: (#200) Requires manage_pages and publish_pages to manage the object
Did not work: OAuthException: (#200) Requires manage_pages and publish_pages to manage the object

Turning off "Make **appname** public?" I get this:

No known Facebook user
OAuthException: (#200) Requires publish_stream permission
Didn't work: OAuthException: (#200) Requires publish_stream permission

I do not need the page to be public-facing but I do want to continue to use the PHP code to write to the pages.

Facebook keeps on refusing to approve the app since:

"Your app doesn't need to submit for manage_pages or publish_pages to post to Pages or blogs that you admin. As an app admin, you can already access these permissions and post to your own timeline, pages and groups. You can provide access to additional users by adding them to your app as admin or developers. Only apply for manage_pages or publish_pages if your app uses a public-facing login that third party users will access externally."

Well I can, but the app can't.

Comment: You are confusing _approval_ of permissions in review, with the user actually _granting_ those permissions to the app. Your OAuth exception means that the token you tried to post with did not include the permissions. So log in as page admin, and grant them to the app.

Comment: I can, using Facebook, go to page xxxx which I manage. How then from that page would I grant permissions to an app?

Comment: You don’t do that “from” the page, a page admin simply has to login via the normal login flow.

Comment: I'm using the app's id, secret and the relevant page's token in a batch job which runs some PHP code. Does the PHP code, via my permissions and tokens, then work without me needing to be logged in? Sorry for the newbie style questions but the FB API document is a bit rubbish. I wish they would at least show some examples :(

Comment: And does your user access token include both manage_pages and publish_pages?

Comment: @MelissaLondon - did you ever find a solution?  My situation is similar - same comment from app review, but I also use FB.login to get each (internal) app admin's list of pages they can post to.  FB.login fails with an error: 'invalid scopes: publish_pages, manage_pages'.  Without the scopes, I get the same OAuth error you got ('Requires manage_pages and publish_pages').  Thanks!